# Send an reminder email after 5 days compare with the timestamp

Tags: google-apps-script

I am intending to send an email after 5 days comparing the timestamp in my google sheet. But it is not working.

Below is my code:

```
function sendEmails() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;  
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, 15)
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
var row = data[i];
var Timestamp = row[0];
var todaydate = new Date();
var secondDate = new Date();
secondDate.setDate(todaydate.getDate()+5);


if (Timestamp <= secondDate){
  var messageHtml = "Hi " + 
    "<br><br>Test " + 
    "<br><br>test" + 
    "<br>Thank You<br><br>";
  var message = messageHtml.replace(/\<br\/\>/gi, '\n').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
  // clear html tags and convert br to new lines for plain mail
  var subject = "Uniform Order Form Pending Process";
  MailApp.sendEmail("test@gmail.com", subject,message);

}
}
};
```

Sorry that maybe it might be something very simple but hope you guys can advise me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
secondDate.setDate(todaydate.getDate()+5 * 86400000);
```

one day is: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, which is 86400000 milliseconds.